# Submit/Simulate keypress HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button , `<input type="button" name="button">` when I click on it I submit a value from another input text `<input type="text" name="btxt">` to a javascript that does some irrelevant action to this question,

Question: Is it possible that I trigger this javascript by pressing return on the keyboard instead of clicking on the button.

Note: These inputs are not inside form tags

Comment: do you want to press return when you are typing the value in de input text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is fully working example (tested on FF 3.5), use a JS library like jQuery to fire event if you need more portability.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Onkeypress Test</title>
<script language="javascript">
function keyDowns(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // If you are using jQuery just write this:
            // $('#testbutton').trigger('click');
            fireClickEvent(document.getElementById('testbutton'));
    }
}
// Event firing is not portable
function fireClickEvent(control) { 
    if (document.all) { 
        control.fireEvent("onclick"); 
    } else { 
        var clickEvent = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvent"); 
        clickEvent.initEvent("click", false, true); 
        control.dispatchEvent(clickEvent); 
    }
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="keyDowns(event);">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Test" id="testbutton" onclick="alert('Clicked to me, you can do whatever')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not? "onkeydown" is an event and if is supported by browser automatically supported by buttons.

Comment: yeah, but you have to focus on the button and then press return to trigger it

Comment: Isn't this the usage scenerio? If not, bind keydown event to the body, and when user presses enter key from anywhere, fire buttons click event.

Comment: but if you want focus on the button first, you dont even need to trigger onkeydown, you just need to press return and it will trigger the click

Comment: I have updated my post, I have tested it on FF 3.5, it may fail on other browsers, you can use a JS library like JQuery to fire event.

Answer (score 2):

well, you can do it easily with form (which doesn't have to actually be submitted):

```
<form onsubmit="return yourAction();">
   <input type="text" name="text" />
   <button type="submit" name="button">Button</button>
</form>
```

and just `return false;` from `yourAction()`

Comment: he dont have form tags arround the input text

Comment: Upvoted this answer because this will also trigger the button if the text field is the active control, and that's usually what you expect. This method also makes it possible to add server side handling of the button click, so that you can support users that don't have JavaScript. I also believe that this solution is the best when accessibility of the web site.

Comment: @TeKapa: Gandalf StormCrow did not say that it was not allowed and/or possible to add the form tag. I would recommend this solution over the one chosen as the answer.

Comment: its better then the choosen one, i agree with you ;)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need you input button.

Try it this way:

```
<input type="text" name="btxt" onkeypress="submitValue(this.value)">

function submitValue(value)
{
  var key;

  if(event.keyCode)
   key= event.keyCode;
  else if(event.wich)
   key=event.wich;

  if(key==13)
   callFunction(value);
}
```

Comment: yes.
then when you type the value, press return and it will call the function you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the **onkeydown** event.  I don't know where you want this event to extend to - the whole web page, or just a part?

Anyway, assuming that you want the onkeydown event to happen to everything in a div tag, e.g.

```
<div id="keyTrapper" onkeydown="trapReturn(event);">
    <input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" />
    <input type="button" name="button" id="myButton" onclick="alert(&quot;Clicked!&quot;);" />
</div>
```

The javascript function you need is:

```
    function trapReturn(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
            myButton.click();
        }
    }
```